# How to loop through the records of a cursor inside another cursor in snowflake procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to loop the inner cursor for each record present in outer cursor. For example:

Outer cursor contains 10 rows and inner cursor contains 2 rows. So 20 rows should get inserted into the table via this snowflake SQL proc.

I am able to insert only 2 records now by using below code.

```
FOR rec2 IN cur2 DO
        acct_num := rec2.ACCT_NUM;
        post_item_num := rec2.POST_ITEM_NUM;
        acc := rec2.ACCTG_DOC_ID; 
        FOR rec1 IN cur1 DO
             fis_yr := rec1.FIS_YR;
             QUERY := 'INSERT INTO INT_P(ACCTG_DOC_ID,ACCT_NUM,POST_ITEM_NUM,FIS_YR) VALUES 
                   (?,?,?,?)';
             execute immediate :QUERY using (acc, acct_num,post_item_num,fis_yr);  
        END FOR;  
    END FOR;
```

Simple join as a workaround cant be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more perfomant to insert all records at once:

```
INSERT INTO INT_P(ACCTG_DOC_ID,ACCT_NUM,POST_ITEM_NUM,FIS_YR)
SELECT ACCTG_DOC_ID, ACCT_NUM,POST_ITEM_NUM, ...
FROM table_name
-- JOIN table_name2   -- outer cursor
--  ON ...
```

---

Using cursor and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT :var_name, ...`:

```
FOR rec2 IN cur2 DO
  acct_num := rec2.ACCT_NUM;
  post_item_num := rec2.POST_ITEM_NUM;
  acc := rec2.ACCTG_DOC_ID; 
  FOR rec1 IN cur1 DO
     fis_yr := rec1.FIS_YR;
     INSERT INTO INT_P(ACCTG_DOC_ID,ACCT_NUM,POST_ITEM_NUM,FIS_YR)      
     SELECT :acc, :acct_num, :post_item_num,: fis_yr;  
  END FOR;  
END FOR;
```

Comment: As I had mentioned in my post,I cant use simple join as for each loop there will be different operations .

Comment: @trainingaz It is possible to achieve it using just `INSERT INTO .... SELECT :variable_name....`

Comment: bind variables are not the issue. After making the changes suggested by you ,I am still getting 2 rows. the outer cursor is not looping further after 1st record. it should iterate the 2 records of inner cursor 10 times and produce 20 records. Individually cursors are looping correctly.

Comment: @trainingaz Please provide reproducible example(table structure, input queries, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open and close the inner cursor in each loop.  So something like this (the open/close for cur2 may not be necessary depending on your use case):

```
OPEN cur2;
FOR rec2 IN cur2 DO
    acct_num := rec2.ACCT_NUM;
    post_item_num := rec2.POST_ITEM_NUM;
    acc := rec2.ACCTG_DOC_ID; 
    OPEN cur1;
    FOR rec1 IN cur1 DO
         fis_yr := rec1.FIS_YR;
         QUERY := 'INSERT INTO INT_P(ACCTG_DOC_ID,ACCT_NUM,POST_ITEM_NUM,FIS_YR) VALUES 
               (?,?,?,?)';
         execute immediate :QUERY using (acc, acct_num,post_item_num,fis_yr);  
    END FOR;  
    OPEN cur1;
END FOR;
CLOSE cur2;
```